# Does this autonomous system of two first-order ODE have a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, recreational-mathematics, nonlinear-system

Let $f:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and let $\delta>0$. Fix initial condition $\vec{x}_0=(x_{10},x_{20})\in [0,1]^2$; time $t$ takes values in $[0,\infty)$. Consider the following system of ODE:
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}_{\color{red}{1}t} = \begin{cases}
\hfill  -\delta \boldsymbol{1}_{(0,1]}(x_{\color{red}{1}t}),& \text{if } f(x_{\color{red}{1}t},x_{\color{blue}{2}t})\leq 0 \\
\hfill 0,& \text{if } x_{\color{red}{1}t}=1 \text{ and } f(1,x_{\color{blue}{2}t})\geq \delta \\
\hfill f(x_{\color{red}{1}t},x_{\color{blue}{2}t})-\delta ,&  \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\dot{x}_{\color{blue}{2}t}=\begin{cases}
\hfill  -\delta \boldsymbol{1}_{(0,1]}(x_{\color{blue}{2}t}),& \text{if } f(x_{\color{blue}{2}t},x_{\color{red}{1}t})\leq 0 \\
\hfill 0,& \text{if } x_{\color{blue}{2}t}=1 \text{ and } f(1,x_{\color{red}{1}t})\geq \delta \\
\hfill f(x_{\color{blue}{2}t},x_{\color{red}{1}t})-\delta ,&  \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Where $\boldsymbol{1}_{\cdot}(\cdot)$ denotes the indicator function. Can this be analytically solved?

The main source of weirdness for me is the fact that the above are piecewise functions. I understand that additional restrictions on $f$ might be needed; if so, please let me know, and I'll add the other assumptions I have in mind. (I chose to omit them for the moment in the interest of not obfuscating my question.)